# c# How to merge elements from different lists one by one to a list of different type

Tags: c#, list, merge

I have a list of a certain type which looks like this:

```
class DestinationType {
    public string FruitName { get; set; }    
    public string VegetableName { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to do is create a list of the above type `DestinationType` and add elements to it from two different List of type string. The lists that have the values that I want to add to DestinationType looks like the ones below:

```
fruitList = List<string> { "apple", "orange" }

vegetableList = List<string> { "celery", "pumpkin" }
```

How can I add the elements from `fruitList` and `vegetableList` such that the end result would look like the one here?

```
List<DestinationList> theCompleteDestinationItem =
 [
    {
        fruitName: "apple",
        vegetableName: "celery"
    },
    {
        fruitName: "orange",
        vegetableName: "pumpkin"
    }
]
```

Comment: Did you mean `List<DestinationType>`, and why will a simple `for (i=0; i<fruitList.Count; i++)` loop where you create each `DestinationType` object not work here? Please try to solve it yourself and ask a _specific question_ about a problem you had in your attempt. [Tour], [ask], [on-topic](/help/on-topic) and [mre]

Comment: Create a constructor for your DestinationType class that takes in 2 stings as parameters. Then append that constructed object to you List<DestinationType>.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`Enumerable.Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netcore-3.1) to combine the elements of both lists then *project* into a type of your choosing or an *anonymous type* or `ValueTuple`

> Applies a specified function to the corresponding elements of two
> sequences, producing a sequence of the results.

**Given**

```
var fruitList = new List<string> {"apple", "orange"};
var vegetableList = new List<string> {"celery", "pumpkin"};
```

**Example**

```
var results = fruitList.Zip(vegetableList, (fruit, vegetable) => new {fruit, vegetable});

foreach (var result in results)
   Console.WriteLine($"{result.fruit}, {result.vegetable}");
```

**Output**

```
apple, celery
orange, pumpkin
```

Or if you have a *readymade* type

```
public class Destination
{
   public string Fruit { get; set; }
   public string Vegetable { get; set; }
}

...

var results = fruitList.Zip(vegetableList, (fruit, vegetable) => 
   new Destination( )
   {
      Fruit = fruit,
      Vegetable = vegetable
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use zip:

```
        var fruitList = new List<string> { "apple", "orange" };
        var vegetableList = new List<string> { "celery", "pumpkin" };
        var fruitAndVeggies = fruitList.Zip(vegetableList, (fruit, veggie) => new DestinationType() { FruitName = fruit, VegetableName = veggie});
```

Comment: I just saw someone beat me to it :)